# Compilation errors for a c api

Tags: c, macos, frameworks

What would be the reason for the following errors though the syntax was right and I have included the coreservices framework in which some data type and constants are declared.

> " c.c:22: error: syntax error before
>   ‘CFFileDescriptorRef’
>
> c.c:22: warning: no semicolon at end
>   of struct or union
>
> c.c:24: error: syntax error before ‘}’
>   token
>
> c.c:24: warning: data definition has
>   no type or storage class
>
> lipo: can't figure out the
>   architecture type of:
>   /var/folders/fF/fFgga6+-E48RL+iXKLFmAE+++TI/-Tmp-//ccFzQIAj.out
>   "

Comment: I would guess you have no semicolon at end of struct or union and that a data definition has no type or storage class.

Comment: Some sample code that reproduces the problem could be quite helpful.

Comment: is the framework C as well? From the name CFFileDescriptorRef one would guess it would be some kind of class.

Comment: You could have forgotten an include that defined a type, forgotten a smicolon, lots  of things. Can you paste the code 10 lines before and after the location that the error indicates?

Comment: @Anders: Its plain C, its from Apples CoreFoundation framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
c.c:22: error: syntax error before ‘CFFileDescriptorRef’
```

... Usually means that you are using a type that is not defined (e.g you forgot to `#include` whatever header defines it before using it).

The following code:

```
foo_t FooBar;
```

Reproduces the error, unless of course `foo_t` is typed somewhere prior to using it.

Or, it could be that you fat fingered whatever came before it :) Kind of hard to tell without seeing the code.